# Python subprocess package returns broken pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to do a very simple example of using subprocess package. The python script should open a new process and run `read` command. `read` command should receive input from stdin via PIPE. Every time when I try to use `write()` and `flush()` it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recorder.py", line 68, in <module>
    p.stdin.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

My python code looks like:

```py
import subprocess
import time


p = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "read",
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True,
    bufsize=1
)

for character in "This is the message!\n":
    p.stdin.write(character.encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.25)
    p.stdin.flush()

assert p.returncode == 0
```

Note: it's very important to send character after character (with sleeping timeout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually could not replicate your result*, in my case your loop runs through and it'd fail on the `assert` as `p` has not finished yet and has no `returncode` (or rather its value is still `None` at that time). Inserting `p.wait()` after the loop and before the `assert` would force we only check for result after `p` has terminated.

Now for the exception you're seeing, it most likely indicates the pipe you're trying to perform `flush()` on is closed. Most likely due to the process having already terminated. Perhaps in your case at that point it already has a (non-zero) `returncode` too which could further help understand the problem?**

---

* On my system `/bin/sh` used by `subprocess.Popen()` with `shell=True` is actually `bash`. Running `["/bin/dash", "-c", "read"]` which presumably happens to be shell called for `/bin/sh` on your system, I got broken pipe as well.

---

** Running dash like this seems to fail with:

> `/bin/dash: 1: read: arg count`

And return `2`.

Which sort of makes it more of a dash question: why calling `/bin/dash -c "read"` (from `python`) fails. It appears that dash `read` (unlike its bash counterpart) always expect at least one variable name to read into as an argument (replace `read` with `read foo`).

---

I guess this python question just became a lesson about assumptions and shell scripts portability. :)